# Find date difference in node.js

Tags: node.js

How to find the date of 15 days ago from the current date using Node.js?

```
For Eg:
Current date is - 10/JAN/2015
15 days ago is - 26/DEC/2014
```

Comment: No... it is not a duplicate. The question is totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for a third party library.  You can get the current time in ms and subtract 15 days worth of milliseconds from it and feed that to a new Date object:

```
var today = new Date();
var old = new Date(today.getTime() - (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Working test harness: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f12Lfvyx/

Answer (score 2):

Use moment.js

```
var moment = require( 'moment' );

var date1 = moment( '25/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
var date2 = moment( '10/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY' );

var diffInMillis = date2.diff( date1 );
var diffDuration = moment.duration( diffInMillis );

console.log( diffDuration.toString() );

// to find a date 15 days ago, substract duration of 15 days
var rightNow = moment();
var before15Days = rightNow.substract( 15, 'days' );

console.log( rightNow.format( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
console.log( before15Days.format( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
```

Comment: agree. use moment js.

Answer (score 1):

use **moment.js**

```
moment().subtract('days', 15);   // subtracts 7 days to current date
```

This [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/managing-dates-times-using-moment-js/) helps you...